# How to list the amazon MWS products in YII2 PHP framework

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, amazon-mws

I am using amazon MWS products API to list all my products available in the amazon seller account. As i have downloaded the PHP code from amazon server it has a set of codes and im running GetMatchingProductSample.php for getting all the products, this is working fine and hence it is core php.

Now my project is in YII 2.0 php framework, I have created a controller and a view for displaying the products page. I dont no how to get the products here.
Since many supportive files are there in folders i dont no how to use them. Im new to yii 2.0 framework. And im using Yii 2.0 advanced framework

This is code of GetMatchingProductSample.php

```
<?php


require_once('.config.inc.php');
// Europe
$serviceUrl = "https://mws-eu.amazonservices.com/Products/2011-10-01";


 $config = array (
   'ServiceURL' => $serviceUrl,
   'ProxyHost' => null,
   'ProxyPort' => -1,
   'ProxyUsername' => null,
   'ProxyPassword' => null,
   'MaxErrorRetry' => 3,
 );

 $service = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Client(
    AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
    AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY,
    APPLICATION_NAME,
    APPLICATION_VERSION,
    $config);
 // @TODO: set request. Action can be passed as MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProduct
 $request = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_GetMatchingProductRequest();
 $request->setSellerId(MERCHANT_ID);

  $request->setMarketplaceId(MARKETPLACE_ID);
  $asin_list = new MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Model_ASINListType();
  $asins = array("0886467918","B00S2SEV7K","B01D3ESEX4");
  $asin_list->setASIN($asins);
  $request->setASINList($asin_list);
 // object or array of parameters
  echo"<pre>";
  print_r($service);
 invokeGetMatchingProduct($service, $request);

  function invokeGetMatchingProduct(MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Interface $service, $request)
  {
      try {
    $response = $service->GetMatchingProduct($request);

    echo ("Service Response\n");
    echo ("=============================================================================\n");

    $dom = new DOMDocument();
    $dom->loadXML($response->toXML());
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $dom->formatOutput = true;
    echo $dom->saveXML();
    echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $response->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");

     } catch (MarketplaceWebServiceProducts_Exception $ex) {
    echo("Caught Exception: " . $ex->getMessage() . "\n");
    echo("Response Status Code: " . $ex->getStatusCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Code: " . $ex->getErrorCode() . "\n");
    echo("Error Type: " . $ex->getErrorType() . "\n");
    echo("Request ID: " . $ex->getRequestId() . "\n");
    echo("XML: " . $ex->getXML() . "\n");
    echo("ResponseHeaderMetadata: " . $ex->getResponseHeaderMetadata() . "\n");
     }
 }
```

Please help me how do i go further from here. if you want i can send you full code set via mail.

Comment: I would say you need a model, that handles this amazon code and all the logic. Then you can call it from controller and display everything with the views. MVC style.

Comment: Ok thanks, Bur where should i keep the supportive files? its some around 20-30 files are there.

Comment: This is a good read: [Working with Third-Party Code](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-yii-integration.html)